# How to change batch size of ImageDataGenerator after instantiating it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The method I am aware of is something like this

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,  
        target_size=(150, 150), 

        batch_size=20,             <---------------------------

        class_mode='binary')
```

But I want to change batch size while training in `model.fit()` method and it won't happen because `batch_size` has already been set in `flow_from_directory()`

So how do I load this dataset so that I've the freedom to change the `batch_size` while training?
All the efforts are highly appreciated

Comment: How about setting the `batch_size` to be `None` in the `train_generator`.

Comment: if batch size is set to non it will default to 32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the batch size after creating the `ImageDataGenerator` object:

```
train_generator.batch_size = 2
```

The batches will then be of size 2.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from **@Nicolas** is correct. You can easily choose the batch size layer after creating a generator. One additional piece of information I like brings here about `batch_size` in the `model.fit`. According to the [doc](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)

> **batch_size**: ... **Do not** specify the `batch_size` if your data is in the form of datasets, **generators**, or `keras. utils.Sequence` instances (since they generate batches).

So, according to the documentation, we shouldn't specify the `batch_size` if we use **generator** as they generate batches for the training.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way it worked for me
I copied the code from keras.dataset.cifar10 and used the link of cats_vs_dogs dataset

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
from tensorflow.python.keras.datasets.cifar import load_batch
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export

dirname = 'cifar-10-batches-py'
origin = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip '
path = get_file(
    dirname,
    origin=origin,
    untar=True,
    file_hash=
    '6d958be074577803d12ecdefd02955f39262c83c16fe9348329d7fe0b5c001ce')

num_train_samples = 50000

x_train = np.empty((num_train_samples, 3, 32, 32), dtype='uint8')
y_train = np.empty((num_train_samples,), dtype='uint8')

for i in range(1, 6):
  fpath = os.path.join(path, 'data_batch_' + str(i))
  (x_train[(i - 1) * 10000:i * 10000, :, :, :],
    y_train[(i - 1) * 10000:i * 10000]) = load_batch(fpath)

fpath = os.path.join(path, 'test_batch')
x_test, y_test = load_batch(fpath)

y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (len(y_train), 1))
y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (len(y_test), 1))

if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
  x_train = x_train.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)
  x_test = x_test.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)

x_test = x_test.astype(x_train.dtype)
y_test = y_test.astype(y_train.dtype)
```

Comment: But you're not using ImageDataGenerator anymore!

Comment: ...or just use `tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs')` instead